# Troubles pushing data to Firebase with a text input field jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am just learning FireBase and have been stuck on this problem for awhile. I am wanting the user to enter a string into the input field press submit, and that data will be sent to FireBase. Any kind of help would be awesome!

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js">
     </script>
     <script>

var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyCBUbK2d_H7QF3J8BDBPHAHSGJAGS",
authDomain: "my-project.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://my-project.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "my-project",
storageBucket: "my-project.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "845405833425"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database;
 database = firebase.database();

var ingInput;

ingInput = $("#fridge");


var submit = $("#submit");
submit.click(sendIng);

//Sends to firebase
function sendIng(){


    //Makes the object
    var data = {
        ingredients: ingInput.text()
    }
    console.log(data);
    var ref = database.ref("ingredients");
    var ingredients = ing.push(data);


    }

   </script>
  </head>
<div id="ingredients-submit">
    <label>Store this item:</label>
<input type="text" id="fridge">
    <button id="submit">Store</button></div>
```